# Change compatibility mode/run as using logon script

Tags: group-policy, compatibility-mode

We have 200+ freshly imaged machines and have learned that in some of them Audacity does not work properly. For some reason, on certain (seemingly random) machines, Audacity needs to be in XPSP3 compatibility mode to run properly and be run as an administrator. Since we have 200+ of these, we are trying to find a way to tell a logon script to change Audacity for us. That way, all we have to do is start the machines and log in. I have looked around and haven't found much. Is this even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set these on a system wide basis you just need to push out a reg file like so:

```
-----------------------------------
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Full\\Path\\To\\File.exe"="WINXPSP3"

-----------------------------------
```

There are additional options if you need them, manually set some yourself and check this registry key.